# Need to Undo the recent path in android draw? Androi

Tags: android

Undo button need to remove paths from drawing. when i need to click again it needs to remove lastpath. It is not to clear all the draw, clear one by one from the last drawn path.Here i am drawing on canvas using path.

```
class DrawingView extends View  {
Paint mPaint;
//MaskFilter  mEmboss;
//MaskFilter  mBlur;
Bitmap mBitmap;
Canvas mCanvas;
Path mPath;
float x,y;
Paint mBitmapPaint;

public DrawingView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(20);

    mPath = new Path();
    mBitmapPaint = new Paint();
    /*mBitmapPaint.setColor(Color.RED);*/
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

if (w==0)
{
w=1080;
}
    if (mBitmap==null)
    {
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    }
    else
    {
      h=  mBitmap.getHeight();
        w=mBitmap.getWidth();
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }
 if (mCanvas==null)

{
mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
}
else
{
mCanvas=null;
mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
 }

}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.draw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

}

private float mX, mY;
private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
    //mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}

private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
}


private void touch_up() {
    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    // commit the path to our offscreen
    mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    //mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SCREEN));
    // kill this so we don't double draw
    mPath.reset();
    // mPath= new Path();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  x = event.getX();
    y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);

            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up();
            invalidate();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}


}
```

Comment: you will have to store all the pathes in the list, and re-draw all of them except the last, if you need to *cancel* the one

Comment: May i know how it can be done in this case i tried but its not working

Comment: before drawing path, save it into a list. And when you undo - clear all canvas, and draw all pathes in the list except the last one. What of this is a problem?

Comment: private ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();                           private ArrayList<Path> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Path>();

This is on draw method

for (Path p : undonePaths) {     canvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);  }
 canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint); canvas.drawPath(mPath,mPaint);

This is undo method
public void onClickUndo () {     if (paths.size()>0)     {         undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size()-1));         invalidate();     }  }

undonePaths.clear(); it is called on on touch start
 
here is my undo code it is not undo the last draw

Comment: sorry, can't read it this way. Add it to the question

Comment: got the undo thanks for the idea but got an issue when i am trying to  redraw remaining paths all the paths are set to recent colors can i know how can we save the colors  that assign to particular paths

Comment: just record not Paths only, but the colors too.